# Using tweepy library with Python in identi.ca

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm using the tweepy library to make a small news application for my desktop in Python. As I've seen in the main web page: http://github.com/joshthecoder/tweepy it has support for identi.ca but I can't manage to log in correctly. To authenticate I do:

```
auth = tweepy.BasicAuthHandler(username, password)
api = tweepy.API(host = 'identi.ca/api')
```

To check if I logged in correctly:

```
if api.verify_credentials() is False:
 print 'Unable to log in, check credentials and server status\n'
 return 1
else:
 print 'Correctly logged in!\n'
 return 0
```

This always returns 1 :(

Some help please? Thank you! :D

P.D.: Of course, username and password are correct credentials :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using just `identi.ca` as the host and setting `api_root` to `/api` would be the correct way to access the identi.ca API, as implied by the [tweepy documentation](http://joshthecoder.github.com/tweepy/docs/api.html#api-reference).